# Join and get Distinct on Foreign Objects/Keys Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Model like this

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get;set;}
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers {get;set;} 
 }

public class Suppliers
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   ...
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

My Linq query is constructed like this to get Products which are unique

```
var suppliers = _context.Products.Where(condition).Select(u => u.Suppliers).ToList(); //
```

The result of this query returns a `List<Iqueryable<Supplier>>` How do I get a list of Supplier Names from this list??

Comment: You need an Interface for the class that implements IEqual so you can use Distinct.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I tried that and it does not work cause the selection (u => u.Suppliers) is a List and not a Supplier so (u => u.name) is not exposed.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change to `SelectMany`. You can just use `_context.Products.Where(condition).SelectMany(u => u.Suppliers).GroupBy(u => u.Name).Select(u => u.First()).ToList()`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That worked Thanks. Add it as answer for me to accept

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Camilo Terevinto this query works.

```
var suppliers = _context.Products.Where(condition).SelectMany(u => u.Suppliers).GroupBy(u => u.Name).Select(u => u.First()).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var supplier_names = _context.Products.Where(condition)
                             .SelectMany(u => u.Suppliers).Select(a => a.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: `.Select(u => u.Suppliers)` part of your answer is not correct